# How to draw border around a bar in MPAndroidChart BarCart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) for drawing a bar chart.
How can I draw border around each bar in the graph that is displayed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is not possible by default.**

You will have to modify the library, specifically the `BarChartRenderer` class.
Simply take the `RectF` object that represents the bar that is to be drawn and draw it once again over the original bar whilst changing the `Paint` mode to `STROKE` instead of `FILL`.

Of course you will also have to change the `Paint` color to distinguish the border from the bar.

Comment: Will try to implement it :)

Comment: use this code:
 `BarDataSet set1;
 set1.setBarBorderWidth(1f);`

Answer (score 0):

So, after a rigorous searching and checking the Demo App the Library Developer used to demonstrate the Library functionalities, I got this.

```
BarChart barChart = new BarChart();

BarData barData = new BarData(barDataSet);

//set the appropriate properties of object **barData**
//then set the data property of the chart
barChart.setData(barData);
.
.
.
.
 //add border to chart bars
    for (IBarDataSet set : barChart.getData().getDataSets())
        ((BarDataSet) set).setBarBorderWidth(set.getBarBorderWidth() == 1.f ? 0.f : 1.f);
.
.
.
//set up other properties as well
```

Answer (score 0):

Intent 
barData.sliceSpace = 2f
and for mas styling
eneficioChar.holeRadius = 1f

Answer (score 0):

```
val set1 = BarDataSet(entries,seriesLabel)
set1.color = Color.YELLOW
set1.barBorderWidth = 1f
set1.barBorderColor=Color.RED
```

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Thanks for answering a question but can you also add an explanation on how your code solves the problem?